# What is the difference between getRichStringCellValue().getString() and getRichStringCellValue().toString()

Tags: java, string, excel, apache-poi

I am currently using Apache POI for handling MS Excel files, and I came across something that seemed weird to me. The HSSFCell class has a method called `getRichStringCellValue()` that returns a `HSSFRichTextString` object. In order to convert this to a normal string, we use `getString()`. Looks like this:

```
cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString()
```

Now what got me wondering is, why is there a `getString()` in the first place, when `toString()` does essentially the same thing, i.e. returns the string equivalent? Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) of `toString()`:

```
toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object
```

The general purpose of `toString()` is to provide a human-readable representation of the object. Some classes go further and specify the detailed format of `toString()`, which is not generally advisable, and if so, then only for the "value objects" (date, time, number).

Unless specified in the class's javadoc, you should never rely on a specific format of the text returned by `toString()`.

The general recommendation: if your class wants to introduce a specific *persistent* text representation, it should be provided by a separate method. Thus you are never unpleasantly surprised if the implementation of `toString()` changes later.

Comment: Yes, formatting is a very critical aspect of POI, so this is probably right. But the underlying implementation is the same, as Vlad mentions in his answer.

Comment: The underlying implementation is none of your business in the object oriented paradigm :-) It may change at any time without warning. What matters for you as the client of class is the **contract** only.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying implementation is the same for both methods:

```
return _string.toString();
```

My guess is they added the getter to be able to use it as a bean property.

BTW: you might want to check for nulls before doing `cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString()`

Comment: Could you pls help me understand? I am not sure what you mean by "bean property".

Comment: @ArvindhMani: JavaBeans are reusable software components for Java. They are classes that encapsulate many objects into a single object (the bean). They are serializable, have a 0-argument constructor, and allow access to properties using getter and setter methods. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans)

Comment: Got it from the wiki. Thanks!